# How can I plot this function with multiple indices?

Tags: plotting

$\prod_{p=4}^{10}\prod_{q=1}^{p} \Big[|\sum_{j^p_q=4}^{p+1} (i Sin \theta)^{|p-j^p_q|}|\Big]$

The summation is indexed by $j^p_q$, where p and q are defined by the  product rule. I was planning to put a for loop for p and within it a for loop for q and then use continuous multiplication within the loop.

P.S> This is my firs time posting a question. Pardon if it looks shabby.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Perhaps you can show what you have tried till now? this will make it much easier for others to help you! What are the values of ip and m?